# Jsf Renderer script Code is uncommended

Tags: javascript, jsf, renderer

i try to put internal JS code into a JS block. This should be done by a custom Renderer for the `h:commandButton`. The Renderer is inbound and works finde. But as soon as i start to generate the script block it is put between `<!--` and `-->`.

So here is the method for generating the script block:

```
     private void writeScript(FacesContext ctx, HtmlCommandButton button, String event, String script) throws IOException {
      String nonce = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
      ResponseWriter writer = ctx.getResponseWriter();
      ctx.setResponseWriter(writer);
      writer.startElement("input", button);
      writer.writeAttribute("type", "submit", null);
      writer.endElement("input");

      writer.startElement("script", button);
      writer.writeAttribute("nonce", nonce, null);
      writer.write("document.getElementById('" + button.getClientId()
         + "')."
         + event
         + " ="
         + " function() {"
         + script
         + "}");
      writer.endElement("script");
   }
```

Also using the `startCDATA()` method doesn't seem to work.

So instead of:

```
<script nonce="...">
document.getElementById('j_id1955899975_7494aa2f:submitButton').alert('hallo') = function() {onclick}
</script>
```

the generated code looks like:

```
    <script nonce="...">
    <!--
document.getElementById('j_id1955899975_7494aa2f:submitButton').alert('hallo') = function() {onclick}
    //-->
    </script>
```

What am I doing wrong ?
Would be really nice if someone could help me :D

Answer (score 0):

According to [Predrag Maric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4074715/predrag-maric)'s [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477025/custom-jsf-component-using-startelement-with-script-results-in-a-comment) i changed code to the following:

```
   private void writeScript(FacesContext ctx, HtmlCommandButton button, String event, String script) throws IOException {
      System.out.println("das event: "+event);
      String nonce = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
      ResponseWriter writer = ctx.getResponseWriter();
      ctx.setResponseWriter(writer);
      writer.startElement("input", button);
      writer.writeAttribute("type", "submit", null);
      writer.writeAttribute("id", button.getClientId(), null);
      writer.endElement("input");
      writer.write("<script>");
      writer.write("document.getElementById('" + button.getClientId()
         + "')."
         + event
         + " ="
         + " function() {"
         + script
         + "}");
      writer.write("</script>");
   }
```

**The problem was writing the script tags with the `writeElement()` method of the `ResponseWriter`** It automatically adds the comments... After coding it out it works, thx a lot !.